# Current JsonReader item is not an object

Tags: c#, json, unit-testing, parsing, json.net

First I made an application and then I've started doing test for it ( Know it is not good way ), everything works fine with parsing etc, but after i made few test got an error :

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException : Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object: StartArray. Path '', line 1, position 1.

Error occurs there `jObject = JObject.Parse(content);` and there `arrayList = JArray.Parse(content);`

```
internal JObject DoParse(string content)
{
    JObject jObject = new JObject();
    if (content != null)
    {
        if (content.Contains("Unable"))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Not found.", "Error");
        }
        else
        {
            jObject = JObject.Parse(content);
        }
    }
    return jObject;
}

internal JArray DoParseOnList(string content)
{
    JArray arrayList = new JArray();
    if (content != null)
    {
        if (content.Contains("Unable"))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Not found.", "Error");
        }
        else
        {

            arrayList = JArray.Parse(content);
        }
    }
    else { }
    return arrayList;
}
```

Any ideas what is wrong ?
Btw. `string content` is json which i got from the server.
Thanks in advance !

### JSON

```
Test Name:  SetGroup
Test Outcome:   Failed
Result Message: SetUp : Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException : Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object: StartArray. Path '', line 1, position 1.
Result StandardOutput:  [{"id":6208,"name":"test"},{"id":6315,"name":"jPOD v144 Testing"},{"id":6306,"name":"iButton Issue"},{"id":6424,"name":"Hybrid"}]
[{"id":6208,"name":"test"},{"id":6315,"name":"jPOD v144 Testing"},{"id":6306,"name":"iButton Issue"},{"id":6424,"name":"Hybrid"}]
[{"enabled":true,"scriptVersion":199,"configVersion":3,"name":"LMU3030 Hybrid Car Test based on 64.112 add ignition on-off"},{"enabled":true,"scriptVersion":199,"configVersion":2,"name":"LMU3030 Hybrid Car Test based on 50.106"},{"enabled":true,"scriptVersion":199,"configVersion":1,"name":"Hybrid car LMU 3030 Ignition test","description":""},{"enabled":true,"scriptVersion":64,"configVersion":113,"name":"based on 64.112 Engineering Build from calamp"},{"enabled":true,"scriptVersion":61,"configVersion":106},{"enabled":true,"scriptVersion":38,"configVersion":117},{"enabled":true,"scriptVersion":184,"configVersion":0},{"enabled":true,"scriptVersion":13,"configVersion":54},{"enabled":true,"scriptVersion":23,"configVersion":105,"name":"PULS Redirect to PROD","description":"Changes just Param 2320 to maint.vehicle-location.com"}]
[]
[{"message":"Not Implemented","vbusDeviceFiles":[],"vbusFileHistories":[]}]
```

Comment: Would be useful to have your JSON as well as that seems to be causing the issue rather than the C# code.

Comment: Could you post the json you get from the server. As per the error the content you are providing to your JObject.Parse() and JArray.Parse() is not appropriate i.e. not a JObject in first case and not a Jarray in the second case.

Comment: Also before debugging everything else, validate your JSON using a service such as http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: I did edit with an Json which i got

Comment: @DerpyUnKnown your JSON is broken. Paste it into the link I gave you above and you'll see the error.

Comment: So it is fail on the server side ?

Comment: Seems like the response is intended to be 4 JSON objects, but as you're deserializing into a single object it's breaking. If you validate the JSON line by line (ie the JSON contained in the `[ ]`) it will validate.

Comment: @JayGould how can i do it line by line ?

Comment: Do what? Validate it or deserialize?

Comment: @JayGould valididate to avoid that error. OK then deserialize

Comment: If you're talking about deserializing it, it would make more sense to fix the server problem than writing a hack to fix the symptom.

Comment: yes try to validate your Json. Here for exemple : http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: @Yanga I linked that above, Derpy doesn't seem to read anything..

Comment: @Yanga  I've read that, I want to say to JayGould that i've done this, It does not solve my problem.

Comment: @DerpyUnKnown No, it wasn't meant to solve your problem. It was meant to identify where your problem was, ie if the issue was your JSON or your C# code. You need to fix whatever is producing the JSON server-side, which we can't help with.

Comment: @JayGould OK! I will speak with guys who are taking care of this server.

Comment: @DerpyUnKnown best of luck.

Answer (score 19):

I have similar issue.
The returned JSON is Array/List but not Object. 
Instead, I use JArray.Parse and it works.

```
jArray = JArray.Parse(content);
```

Answer (score 3):

I ran into a very similar problem. The reason my JObject.Parse(json) would not work for me was because my Json had a beginning "[" and an ending "]". In order to make it work, I had to remove those two characters. I would inspect your Json and make sure that it starts with a { and ends with a }.

For me, I removed the first and last characters.

```
jsonResult = jsonResult.TrimStart(new char[] { '[' }).TrimEnd(new char[] { ']' });
```

Comment: This solved my issue. API was returning JSON enclosed in`[` and `]`. Thank a bunch!

Comment: What about the case of a nested array? Is the parser so weak that I have to detect each sub item and make sure those are objects and not arrays?

Comment: there is a name for this.. those two magical characters [ and ] means you are looking at a json-array... instead of a json-object which would be enclosed by { and }

Answer (score -1):

@joedotnot is exactly right - look for [ or {.  Interestingly WordPress API returns both depending on the context which makes parsing the JSON object or array of objects fun...  JObject is also not a great choice for a variety of others reasons, any malformed JSON and it will bomb out, much better to deserialise into your type, a good guide is [here](https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2019/09/11/how-to-parse-json-in-net-core/) which is applicable anywhere JSON.NET is used.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32458024)