# Newtonsoft.Json: Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object: StartArray

Tags: c#, json.net

Hi I am passing the below string in my code in line             `var json = JObject.Parse(jStr);` and I get the error as

> System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Function1.
> Newtonsoft.Json: Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current
> JsonReader item is not an object: StartArray.

Can someone please explain me how should I fix this. Is it because it is an array kind? At the end my passed string will be an array. how can I fix this?. here is the sample string(one object from the array) which I am passing in above line

```
[
  {
    "_id": "_AUQ9",
    "im:SiceErrors": {
      "errors": [
        {
          "_id": "O9UQ9_0",
          "ErrorMessage": "Uype",          
          "Parameter": "r:type",
          "ParameterValue": "[\n  \"~:bbl:P924\",\n  \"~:corer:ag\"\n]",
          "RefObjectParameter": "type_key",
          "Project": "NPOS+1"
        }
      ]
    },
    "cullad-tag:Cject": "P|GT",
    "bbl:P1014": "PIGT",
    "cullad-tag:MoomosBaseObjectDescription": "Gate Valve",
    "bbl:P3935": "Gve",
    "cullad-tag:CreateDate": "15.10.2021",
    "cullad-tag:MoomosDescription": "P2",
    "cullad-tag:MoomosUID": "A49",
    "bbl:011772": "UQ9",
    "cullad-tag:Description": "P2",
    "cullad-tag:Discipline": "U",
    "bbl:P101001445": "bbl:P163",
    "cullad-tag:FLabel": "FFeed",
    "bbl:P1094": "pd:P1299",   
    "bbl:P10791": "V",
    "cullad-tag:FutureTag": "No",
    "cullad-tag:IndexType": "MV",
    "bbl:P138": "bbl:P1563",
    "cullad-tag:IsTopTag": "No",
    "bbl:P7": "No",
    "cullad-tag:MountedOn": "F-18UD800",
    "bbl:P4024": "F-18800",   
    "bbl:P1834": "pd:P1094",    
    "bbl:P1803": "8120",
    "cullad-tag:SubProjectCategory": "Feed",
    "cullad-tag:SubProjectName": "SUB",
    "cullad-tag:System": "18",
    "bbl:P01660": "bbl:P15326",
    "cullad-tag:TagNumber": "F-120",
    "bbl:P10022": "F-20",   
    "cdf:type": [
      "bbl:P10924",
      "bbl:P101907",
      "bbl:P101003632",
      "bbl:P13932",
      "bbl:P21",
      "iso15926:InanimatePject",
      "iso15926:Object",
      "Moomos:PopoFeedTag"
    ],
    "primarycdf:type": "bbl:P924"
  }
]
```

Comment: Yes, your JSON is an array.  Attempt something like: `var array = JArray.Parse(jStr);`.

Comment: see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40790217/current-jsonreader-item-is-not-an-object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to wrap your string to make a valid json object:

```
var json = JObject.Parse("{ \"Data\":" + jStr + "}");
```

The resulting object will contain property **Data** with data from json

**edited by comments:** OR try this approach:

```
foreach(JObject obj in JArray.Parse(jStr))
{
    // todo: pass an object to a method that requires an JObject to process
}
```

Comment: Absolutely not, this is perfectly valid JSON (RFC 8259)

Comment: but then that will be with "Data" as key. I am trying to modify my values in the json

Comment: my jobject is later passed to another method which takes a Jobject but not an array

Comment: @NicolasVoron I edited my answer and add word object: ...a valid json **object**

Comment: @ZZZSharePoint Your question was how to fix it. What object is required to get in the end to pass on, I can't know. This is a completely different question
Please provide the resulting JObject structure to use

Comment: your answer bring extra "Data" key in the json. that will end in wrong output which wich will later be read by my models

Comment: @ZZZSharePoint You can name it whatever you want, but if further JObject is required, then the array must be nested in the property

Comment: if I do your way, I dont get the result, now The json passed to my model becomes different. however, if I do something like this jStr = jStr.TrimStart(new char[] { '[' }).TrimEnd(new char[] { ']' }); I have my valid json which I want to pass

Comment: but that is not I would like to do, instead I would prefer some way where each object of array is being passed , something in loop one by one

Comment: @ZZZSharePoint add this details to your question. And look at my edits, maybe it will help you

Comment: change var obj to Jobject obj and now it works

Comment: @ZZZSharePoint I figured out your problem, but you confirmed the answer to someone else, why? Just wondering

Comment: because that was correct..and gave exact result.

Comment: @ZZZSharePoint But my answer was correct and was first instead of a minor typo.

Answer (score 3):

Your example is a single object inside an array.

@SeeSharp propose to wrap that array.

The opposite way is, if that's always the case, that you can just parse the object inside that array (removing first and last character):

```
var json = JObject.Parse(jStr.Remove(str.Length - 1).Remove(0, 1));
```

Otherwise, I guess you just adapt your code to handle an array, and not an object (which looks the better way to do so)

EDIT :

Since there is multiple object inside your JArray, just iterate over it :

```
foreach (JObject item in JArray.Parse(jStr)) 
{
  DoStuffOnJObject(item) // call your method
}
```

Comment: right and that works, i tried that. But I would like some way that I take each object in the array and pass them one by one . How do i do that?

Comment: there are multiple objects in the array, i just gave one to show the sample